# Python Lambda Function to check replication status on Secrets Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to write a Lambda Function in Python to check Secrets in Secrets Manager to see if Replication is turned on. I have the following Python Script:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Specify the name of the secret to check
    secret_name = "sandbox/blah"

    # Initialize the Secrets Manager client
    client = boto3.client("secretsmanager")

    try:
        # Get the secret details
        response = client.describe_secret(SecretId=secret_name)

        # Check if replication is enabled
        replication_status = response.get("ReplicationStatus")
        print(replication_status)

        if replication_status == "Enabled":
            result = f"Replication is enabled for secret '{secret_name}'."
        else:
            result = f"Replication is not enabled for secret '{secret_name}'."

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": result
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
        }
```

Now replication_status is not showing as enabled from what I can tell. When I see the output of print(replication_status) it is showing the following:

[{'Region': 'us-west-2', 'KmsKeyId': 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:923339306134:key/mrk-44f2ee3a2b4546348dbbe0fb1d06151b', 'Status': 'InSync', 'StatusMessage': 'Replication succeeded'}]

Ultimately I would like a way to have it look in this string for Status == InSync, or StatusMessage == Replication succeeded or something like that.

I am extremely new to Python, so I apologize if I messed anything up here. Most of my experience has been with Powershell and Bash, so I feel like I am missing something pretty easy.

Thanks!

I am trying to have the python read the output of Relication_status for specific strings in the output.

Comment: You can test the Status with `if replication_status["Status"] == "InSync":`. Similarly for StatusMessage.

Comment: @jarmod now I get the following error: An error occurred: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Ah, replication_status is a list, so use `replication_status[0]["Status"]` to test the first item in the list. If there can be more than 1 (maybe there can, I don't know so you should research) then you might also need to deal with that later.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the documentation below -
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager/client/describe_secret.html

Then you should be getting the replication status like below -

```
# Check if replication is enabled
replication_status = response.get("ReplicationStatus")
replication_status = replication_status[0]["Status"]
```

Please note the replication_status can have any of the below 3 values -

**Failed**, which indicates that the replica was not created.

**InProgress**, which indicates that Secrets Manager is in the process of creating the replica.

**InSync**, which indicates that the replica was created.